# cmake change build dir in clion

Tags: c, cmake, clion

Is there a way how to pass build dir to CLion? The command that is executed is

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /old/path/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/ba070dfe/ba070dfe/Debug --target clean -- -j 4
```

But I would like to have something like

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /new/path --target clean -- -j 4
```

I have tried several options both in [CMake](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling) and [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/quick-cmake-tutorial.html) but none of them impacts the result.

Answer (score 0):

Clion currently doesn't fully support paths like this yet, however, you can go to the Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake tab, and tell it to select the binaries into a specific location. Optionally you can set them yourself in cmakelists and run it via terminal/cmd. Also check all of the options in the build configurations, and you might find answers there.

Comment: I was hitting those tabs hard, it would be nice to show what and where should I type in.

Comment: The build output tab is literally right in the CMake tab in Build, Execution, Deployment. Just give it a path, and it will dump the executables there.

Comment: it does not work. That was the first field I had filled.